# How do I declare a public variable in C# that should be accessible to ALL classes in the project?

Tags: c#

I have a list as follows in a class:

```
public string[] Locations = { "home",
                              "office",
                              "vehicle" };
```

(The actual string/list is hundreds of items long I just shortened it for the sake of this post)

In another class, I am trying to reference it with:

```
string location = Locations[myRand.Next(Locations.Length)];
```

Though it does not recognize "locations" as a string.

How do I make it to where all the classes can see it? Also, do they have to be within the same namespace for this to work? Or is there a way to make the list available to ALL namespaces and classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By declaring it as `public` it is already visible to all namespaces.  The issue is how to access it.  What you want is `static`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string[] Locations = { "home",
                          "office",
                          "vehicle" };
}
```

Then you access it as:

```
string s = MyClass.Locations[1];
```

If it's not static, then you need an *instance* of the class to access it:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
string s = m.Locations[1];
```

Comment: A word of caution though - it is seldom a good design decision to use global state (there are a few exceptions).

Comment: Level 1 improvement would be to make it `readonly`, level 2 it becomes an `enum`.

Comment: @Ian

string location = Lists.Locations[myRand.Next(Lists.Locations.Length)];

worked! thanks so much!

Comment: @Eric what do you mean by global state? This is a personal program for just my use, but I would like to learn best practices.

Comment: @user47368 what you doing feels like [stringly typed code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) which generally frowned upon. Such strings should likely be either enum values OR coming from resources (if you really looking for good practice), also using resources is likely too much for any personal tool. Also as mentioned `static` is frequently overused - feel free to pick side you like in discussion found by https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+why+static+is+bad

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a "utils" function, to be called anywhere. Maybe create a new workspace for "utilities, and declare your function static in a file inside that workspace as Ian said.